# Cocoapods library not found for apple watch extensions

Tags: ios, cocoapods, apple-watch, ios-extensions

Here is my PodFiles, as apple watch extension only need part of the library in the main app.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '7.0'


######################
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
#source 'https://github.com/albertodebortoli/ADBCocoaPodsRepository.git'

target 'MyAppDev WatchKit Extension', :exclusive => true do
pod 'MagicalRecord/Core+Logging', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git'
pod 'BlocksKit'
pod 'EncryptedCoreData'
end

# Logging
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'   #2.0.0-beta4 at the moment

# Networking
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
#pod 'IADownloadManager'
#pod 'TCBlobDownload'
#pod 'ObjectiveCDM', '~> 1.0.5'

#pod 'librabbitmq-objc'

# Database
pod 'MagicalRecord/Core+Logging', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git'
#pod 'couchbase-lite-ios'

######################
pod 'StompKit'
######################
#pod 'MQTTKit', :git => 'https://github.com/iosphere/MQTTKit'

# Utilities
pod 'XMLDictionary'
pod 'THObserversAndBinders'
pod 'CocoaSecurity'
pod 'KVOController'
pod 'INTULocationManager'
pod 'zipzap'
pod 'libextobjc'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
pod 'EncryptedCoreData'
pod 'LPGoogleFunctions'

# UI
pod 'BFPaperButton', '~> 1.5.7'
pod 'SWTableViewCell', '~> 0.3.6'
pod 'FXImageView', '~> 1.3.5'
pod 'MZFormSheetController' , '~> 2.4.1'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
#pod 'UITableView-AnimationControl'
#pod 'SlackTextViewController'
pod 'QBImagePickerController'
pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.6'
pod 'BlocksKit'
pod 'SIAlertView'
pod 'SZTextView'

pod 'ACEDrawingView'
pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor'

pod 'RBStoryboardLink'

pod 'AMPPreviewController'
```

when I build the target, I got the following error 
library not found for -lPods-EncryptedCoreData
but I did include EncryptedCoreData Library in both targets.

any idea?